# Crypt_GPG getting error while doing concurrent request to encrypt & sign data

Tags: gnupg

I'm using this script to encrypt and sign data.

```
`$gpg = new Crypt_GPG(['digest-algo' => "SHA256", 'cipher-algo' => "AES256", 'compress-algo' => "zip", "homedir" => "/home/ubuntu/.gnupg", "debug" => true]);

$gpg->addSignKey($clientKey, $passphase);
$gpg->addEncryptKey($serverKey);

$signedMessage = $gpg->encryptAndSign(json_encode($messageBody));`
```

I found below error in debug log:

```
Crypt_GPG DEBUG: GPG error stream ready for reading

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: => about to read 65536 bytes from GPG error

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: => read 80 bytes

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: ERROR: gpg: signing failed: End of file

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: ERROR: gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: End of file

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: GPG status stream ready for reading

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: => about to read 65536 bytes from GPG status

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: => read 69 bytes

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: STATUS: BEGIN_ENCRYPTION 2 9

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: STATUS: FAILURE sign-encrypt 33570815

Crypt_GPG DEBUG: => subprocess returned an unexpected exit code: 2
```

Getting above error while doing concurrent request while encrypting and sign data. e.g. 10 request per second

I'm expecting it should work for atleast 5-10 concurrent request.